# How to calculate two input text values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate the total prices of products using the input text values.

The html code and javascript snippet are as follows:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes

var firstValue = parseFloat($('#value1').val()) || 0; // get value of field
var secondValue = parseFloat($('#value2').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float



var subtotal1 = firstValue * 10;
var subtotal2 = secondValue * 15;

    
$('#subtotal1').html(subtotal1); // output it
$('#subtotal2').html(subtotal2); // output it
$('#finaltotal').html(subtotal1 + subtotal2); // output it
});
```

```html
<!-- Product 1 -->
  <div>      
   <label>Product 1</label>
   <div><input type="text" id="value1"><?php echo ' x 10USD = ';?><span id="subtotal1"></span>USD</div> 

<!-- Product 2 -->
  <div>      
   <label>Product 2</label>
   <div><input type="text" id="value2"><?php echo ' x 15USD = ';?><span id="subtotal2"></span>USD</div> 
 
 <!-- Total -->
  <div>      
   <label>Total:</label>
   <div><span id="#finaltotal"></span>USD</div>
 </div>
```

The final result should be something like the following:
[1 ] x 10USD = 10USD
[2 ] x 15USD = 30USD
Total: 40USD

However, the above code does not work properly.
Is there a good way to get it done?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to elaborate on "does not work properly". Otherwise there is no way for us to know what is happening.

Comment: remove "#" from the #finaltotal id

Comment: @survartheec. Thank you. I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo. `<span id="#finaltotal"></span>` should be `<span id="finaltotal"></span>`

Updated snippet:

```js
$('input').keyup(function() { // run anytime the value changes
  var firstValue = parseFloat($('#value1').val()) || 0; // get value of field
  var secondValue = parseFloat($('#value2').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
  var subtotal1 = firstValue * 10;
  var subtotal2 = secondValue * 15;
  $('#subtotal1').html(subtotal1); // output it
  $('#subtotal2').html(subtotal2); // output it
  var finalAnswer = (subtotal1 + subtotal2).toString();
  $('#finaltotal').html(finalAnswer.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, ",")); // output it
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Product 1 -->
<div>
  <label>Product 1</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="value1">
    <?php echo ' x 10USD = ';?><span id="subtotal1"></span>USD</div>

  <!-- Product 2 -->
  <div>
    <label>Product 2</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="value2">
      <?php echo ' x 15USD = ';?><span id="subtotal2"></span>USD</div>

    <!-- Total -->
    <div>
      <label>Total:</label>
      <div><span id="finaltotal"></span>USD</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question: If the total value exceeds 1000 USD, can I insert a thousand separator (comma)?

Comment: You can do this using a regex. `"10000000".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, ",")`. I've updated my snippet with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Remove hash from id attribute, `id="finaltotal"`

```
<label>Total:</label>
<div><span id="#finaltotal"></span>USD</div>

               ^-----------remove-----------
```

It works!

http://jsfiddle.net/4edbv96r/